# c++ assignment inches to cm conversion table

Tags: c++, loops, dev-c++

So I'm taking a basic algorithm development class which uses c++ and I am very new to the language. One of the program writing assignments is very difficult so I decided to ask here. I am not looking for outright answers just some a finger to point me I the right path.

This is my assignment:

Write a program that displays an inch to a centimeter conversion table. Your input will be the smallest number of inches and the largest number of inches to be converted. The intervals will be in 6-inch increments. One inch is equivalent to 2.54 centimeters.

We just went over the three types of looping structures namely, the For loop, the While Loop, and the Do While Loop. Which do I use for which part of the program?

Comment: For loop works best for iterating over a set or range. While loop works best for continuing until a condition is false. I've almost never used a do-while loop.

Comment: If you're incrementing by a static value, for loops are fantastic.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Two things: 1) everything @MooingDuck said, except that do-while loops are good for doing things that you know you want to at least once and 2) can you clarify what part specifically you need help with?

Answer (score 0):

A for loop would be a good choice in this case.
To give you a head start:

```
#Take the smallest and largest numbers in input
for(float i = smallest ; i <= largest ; i = i+6 ){
    #do your calculations
    #Print out the number , endline
}
```

Comment: While I agree this is probably the best one for the job, really any will do. It just depends on how you want to do it.

Comment: does the 'largest' value necessarily need to be printed?  it is unclear from the OP's problem statement.

Comment: The largest and smallest values are the limits for the range of numbers to be converted. Say smallest = 10 , largest = 200. So, you would convert number between 10 and 200 (included).

Comment: @MFisherKDX Since the table increments in values of 6 the last value has to be a multiple of six + the initial number to be listed. Say the first number is 1 and the last is 36, the conversions of 1, 7, 13, 19, 25, 31 would be listed.  the last value 36 wouldn't be.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response @TaimoorAli

Comment: My pleasure @AbdullahKaanCetin

Comment: *The largest and smallest values are the limits for the range of numbers to be converted. Say smallest = 10 , largest = 200. So, you would convert number between 10 and 200 (included)* -- @TaimoorAli -- I agree.  But your loop will not print 200.  The last value it will print is: '196'. That is my point with the question.

Comment: How would you do that?

Comment: @TaimoorAli has already given you crux of the problem.  I suggest studying what he gave you and figuring out the rest.  ;)